# Loading JSON data into Handsontable from S3 using AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, amazon-s3

I'm trying to pre-populate Handsontable spreadsheets with data on page load. My JSON files are stored on S3. I am able to load the data from S3 with AJAX successfully, but after that I'm failing to fill the plugin with the data I retrieve. My current code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {


  var objectData = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
      return data;
    }
  }),
  container = document.getElementById('example'),
  hot;

  hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: objectData,
    colHeaders: true,
    minSpareRows: 1
  });

});
```

I don't get any errors, but maybe the data does not manage to load on time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how `$.ajax` works. A return in `success` does nothing and `objectData` is a promise object, not the response data

Try:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/path/to/file.json",
  dataType: 'json',
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(data) {

    new Handsontable($('#example')[0], {
      data: data,
      colHeaders: true,
      minSpareRows: 1
    });
  }
}).fail(function() {
  console.log('Request failed, inspect arguments for details')
})
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my errors. For some reason I thought that placing data into a variable and loading it after that would be a good idea.